# How do I get this alert to stop looping?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have this Javascript code where I want the users submission to only be pushed to the database, when all of the values are filled. The only problem is, a user can input a new row of data and that needs to be checked with a loop. Every time I go to click submit, the data is pushed regardless if the fields are filled or not. And it loops each time. I've tried moving `data.push(assetInfo);` outside the brackets and it still prints submission accepted how ever many times the user clicks submit. Any help would be appreciated!

```
$('#submit').click(() =>{
        $('form').on('submit', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();

    
            //Format all Data into JSON for Submission
            let data = [];

            // Iterate over all rows and store data
            for (let i = 1; i <= count; i++){

                // Skip Row if it was Removed
                if (!$(`tr[index=${i}]`).length) continue;

                // Store all Info from this row
                let assetInfo = {

                    asset_tag_no: $(`#asset_tag_no${i}`).val(),
                    manufacturer: $(`#manufacturer_serial_no${i}`).val(),
                    descriptions: $(`#description${i}`).val(),
                    costs: $(`#cost${i}`).val(),
                    po_no: $(`#po_no${i}`).val(),
                    remarks: $(`#remarks${i}`).val(),
                }
        
                if (assetInfo.asset_tag_no && assetInfo.manufacturer && assetInfo.descriptions && assetInfo.costs && assetInfo.po_no && assetInfo.remarks  != ''){ 
                    alert('Submission Accepted');
                }
                // Add Info to array
                data.push(assetInfo);
            }
    
        
            // Upload JSON to Database
            console.log(data);
        });
    });
  })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to move the `push` outside the brackets. You need to move it *inside* the brackets:

```
            if (assetInfo.asset_tag_no && assetInfo.manufacturer && assetInfo.descriptions && assetInfo.costs && assetInfo.po_no && assetInfo.remarks  != ''){ 
                alert('Submission Accepted');
                // Add Info to array
                data.push(assetInfo);
            }
```

EDIT

If you want to push a row exactly once, then you can replace

```
if (!$(`tr[index=${i}]`).length) continue;
```

with

```
    let currentRow = $(`tr[index=${i}]`);
    if ((!currentRow.length) || (currentRow.hasClass("submitted"))) continue;
    currentRow.addClass("submitted");
```

Comment: Even when I move it inside the brackets and I look at the console log, if I clicked submit 4 times in the html, when everything is filled out it gets pushed to the database like 8 times. In the console I'll see the database was updated 8 times when it should only be one

Comment: @privaterabbit1 I understand this problem, yet, your expectation for this was not mentioned. Do you want to mark rows that were already saved and avoid pushing them? Is this the goal?

Comment: @privaterabbit1 for the case when you need to submit a record exactly once, I have edited my answer above, the idea is that we can check for a `submitted` class as well when we validate the row and, if it was valid, we add the `submitted` class, so the row will have that class the next time it is validated.

Comment: Thank you so much Im going to test this out now!

Comment: @privaterabbit1 you are welcome. Please let me know about the results. If there are still problems, let me know. If everything is working well, then you can accept my answer as the correct answer.